# Key Pressed acting as Key Typed

Tags: java, swing, keyboard

I ran into a small problem when I tried to implement a `KeyEventDispatcher`. Holding down any key on the keyboard will cause `QuestGUI` to switch between true and false. Meaning it checks if the key is pressed every execution. What I want is when I press ´A´ it will trigger an event for my `KeyEventDispatcher` to handle. Then it should wait untill the next key is pressed. My code looks as following.

**Test.java**

```
package core;

import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test
{
    public Test (){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();        
        frame.setResizable (false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setSize (800, 600);        
        frame.setVisible (true);

        KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyManager());
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        new Test();
    }
}
```

**KeyManager.java**

```
package core;

import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyManager implements KeyEventDispatcher {

    private boolean QuestGUI;

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
            QuestGUI = !QuestGUI;
            System.out.println("QuestGUI" + QuestGUI);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It could be solved by adding a `boolean` to check if Q was pressed, it will only work once Q is released. Like `PRESSED_Q`. Then I need that for every keybind and match against it. However, that feels clunky. I expected `KEY_PRESSED` would do this automatically.

Comment: Look at the documentation for KeyListener, you want keyPressed.:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html If it is behaving as you suggest then you answered the question yourself, track the behavior with a boolean value. It seems as though you're implementing a "toggle" feature, you could track it via pressed and released.

Comment: So there is no better option than that clunky one?

Comment: In my experience, no. Then again I have not done low level Swing/AWT in about 4 years. There might be a better option. My understanding of the issue is that something is constantly issuing KEY_PRESSED events. If that event is constant you need to track the Down/Up yourself. You could consider extending the classes and creating an API that makes more sense or simply use a tracking method of `if(e.KEY_PRESSED){down = true;} else if(e.KEY_RELEASED) {down = false;}` and then track via `down`

Comment: Have you considered using the key bindings APi instead?  [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: A key press event will be triggered at a regular interval (based on the OS), so your boolean will continuously flip between true to false.  You need to be able to detect the `PRESS` and `RELEASE` separately.  You might consider using a `Map` of some kind, keyed to the `KeyEvent`'s virtual key code

Comment: @MadProgrammer, as I suspected. I also want to avoid using key binds as I want to centralize it. That might be a bad idea or?

Comment: Key bindings can centralised, attach them to the core component and use `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`. Personally I think using a `KeyDispatcher` might be a little bit of overkill (IMHO - and yes, I've probably done something similar in the past).  You could also use a `AWTListener`, but you'd still have the same problems. It all comes down to what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Personal, a key binding for press and release, which has the map key for the key seems like a more configurable solution (ie, you could bind "up" to whatever key you want and not have to change your code when you change it)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer to use key bindings for this kind of thing, that's just me, but you could create two `Action`s, one for pressed and one for released, which simply took a "key" value which would set a value in a `Map` of some kind (ie `"Up"`) to `true`/`false` depending on the trigger, but that's me...

The core issue is, a `KEY_PRESSED` event will be repeated at a regular interval, based on the OS.  This means that your `QuestGUI` value is constantly been flipped.  You need to detect the `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` events and take appropriate actions, for example...

```
public class KeyManager implements KeyEventDispatcher {

    private boolean QuestGUI;

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED && !QuestGUI) {
            QuestGUI = true;
            System.out.println("QuestGUI" + QuestGUI);
        } else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED && QuestGUI) {
            QuestGUI = false;
            System.out.println("QuestGUI" + QuestGUI);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You could also use the `KeyEvent#getKeyCode` value, placing this in a `List` or `Map` to detect when certain keys are pressed/released...

Personally, I think key bindings would be easier to manage, expand and configure, but I guess that all comes down to context.

Comment: Your solution is what I did implement now; http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80630/implementation-of-keyeventdispatcher-in-java .